# My manager is obstructing me from doing my job, and it's creating a hostile environment. Where can I draw the line without appearing insubordinate?

Tags: management, ethics, unprofessional-behavior

I work in the IT department of a small company, and over the past year, my original manager left, leaving me with a new manager who is not particularly fond of me. For the most part, my new manager has just left me to do my job and avoided interacting with me, operating under the assumption that I will get whatever work done that I need to without his intervention.

Though it’s a far from ideal arrangement, I have tried to make the best of it and I intend to leave as soon as I find a new position. For the time being, the problem I am facing is related to any instances where I need to interact with my manager to involve his decision-making authority. He has gone out of his way to routinely deny requests for equipment purchases, software licenses, etc.

Many of my coworkers have also experienced the same issue when making requests through my manager. Because of this, they tend to come to me first for any IT-related request. My manager gets upset about this and tells me that they shouldn’t be coming to me with those request (even though I have zero control over people coming to me). Nonetheless, whenever someone does come to me with some type of request, I simply tell them to make the same request with my manager, and I avoid relaying the request to him since he doesn’t want me to do that.

Because many IT-related requests are getting stalled with my manager, there has been a great among of company-wide frustration directed at the IT department. In particular, members of upper management are well aware of the issues with my manager, but they have proceeded to chew me out on a number of occasions related to things like slowness and lag with our internal systems due to insufficient hardware, or the inability to get equipment purchased. They very well know that I can’t do anything about it, but they have been acting increasing hostile about it.

I feel that the line needs to be drawn somewhere, but it is not clear how to do that without being perceived as insubordinate to other managers.

Comment: Have you talked with upper management about what is going on?  You say they understand what is happening but they still chew you out.  Why?

Comment: I'm not really seeing the "hostile" aspect here, it sounds more like your manager is just negligent, are you referring to upper management chewing you out? Can you clarify more what that means? Depending on what it means, answers may vary.

Comment: Upper management is aware of what is going on. I have discussed the issue with them and they agree there is a problem. Knowing all that, they have still have proceeded to chew me out several times, as if we had never discussed my concerns. That what I was referring to as the hostile aspect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> In particular, members of upper management are well aware of the issues with my manager, but they have proceeded to chew me out on a number of occasions...

These are opportunities to discuss what action you've taken to attempt to resolve the issue and the **specific** reason those actions were unsuccessful. "Bob never approves any requests." is a terrible answer; "I applied to have the server replaced when the 2018 budget was being established but it wasn't approved.  You'd have to talk to Bob about how the annual budget was established as that's out of my hands." is a much better answer.  It shows what action you've taken to attempt to resolve the situation and managers will understand clearly that this is decided above your pay grade.

Major bonus points if you can point them to the proper process of asking your manager directly for the solutions.  This both satisfies the manager that they control their area and points out to users that the manager is the one making the decisions that negatively impact them.

As an aside to this, how sure are you that upper management is aware that the manager is the problem?  Are they the type of person who may be actively throwing you under the bus?  You may want to be sure that you are keeping a paper trail on instances where you think that your manager's decisions are not in the best interest of the company.

Comment: To link this answer and @PeteCon's, any requests for budget, licenses or hardware can also go through the ticketing system as well. This way a papertrail is easily established.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an issue tracking system in place? If not, set one up, and then request that all people enter their issues directly into it. Assign all issues to your manager, and he can then reassign them to you when he needs to.

The advantage of this is that people will stop coming to you, and you will be able to see how many issues are stalled by your manager because they're not reaching you. Eventually this information may be very useful for higher management in some way...

Comment: We have one, but there is very little management support for getting anyone to actually use it. They perceive it to be a waste of people's time.

Comment: @it-guy Fuck management. Stop doing work unless it's on the system. Redirect all future requests to the system. It'll take a few weeks but they'll get there.